.NET MAUI Android App has Random Page Navigation
This just might be the weirdest MAUI bug on record.  I am experiencing some VERY strange behavior with the RELEASE build of our MAUI Android App. This is very difficult to describe.  Please bear with me:
I am seeing a "random" page navigation when certain actions take place, but only in RELEASE builds.  Specifically, if I click on a certain button or, say, select from a picklist, that would otherwise result in simply putting a string into an editor control, the app will instead navigate to our Azure login page!
The code that is (somehow) getting invoked is the MicrosoftIdentityClient.PublicClientApplicationBuilder that transfers control to an Azure login page.  BUT... this happens from locations in our app that are NOT calling this code!!!
There is no correlation or similarities between the different locations in the app that cause the random page navigation.  At least, none that I can see.
My assumption was that some sort of bug in the release build optimization was causing a jump vector to be wrong - very weird.  But as far as I can tell, I have turned OFF all optimization in release mode, but the problem persists.
Since this is a release build, I cannot set breakpoints in code to see how/why this is happening.
SO: What could be causing this and how to fix it?  How to debug it?
Any and all ideas are very welcome.
MORE ON THIS.  It looks like exceptions thrown under a release build are not caught in exception handling:
Here is code and logs generated when running under a DEBUG build and a RELEASE build:
   try
   {
      Flog.Info("Force exception. Should be caught and logged next...");
      object someObj = null; 
      someObj.GetType();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Flog.Error(e); // Log error
   }

Here is the log under RELEASE BUILD:
    [2024-08-26][18:50:01.0863]:INFO:Force an exception. Should be caught and logged next...
    // (and nothing else logged - app crashes)

Under DEBUG...
    [2024-08-26][18:56:07.0897]:INFO:Force exception.  Should be caught and logged next...
    [2024-08-26] 
    [18:56:11.0326]:ERROR:DescriptionModels.DescriptiveText:Object reference not set to an instance of an object....

SO... it is crystal clear that under a RELEASE build exceptions are not caught.
WHY IS THIS?  Is there a compiler switch of some sort?

You need to add logging to the suspect code in order to narrow down the cause

Yes, @Jason.  I've put a lot of logging in.  It seems this is related to an exception thrown in a sequence of code that gets "hit" from different places in the app.  There is an error being thrown due to a null ref.  I handle it, but it is only "caught" in debug mode.  In a release build, the app abends and "falls in the pond". I removed the login redirect - looks like that left a page on the stack when the app faults. After removing it, that page no longer appears - the app just crashes).
Does MAUI treat exception handling differently in a release build?  It seems to. ?

How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

I intend to do this today.  It's a complex app, so reducing it to a simple example in isolation is a bit tricky.  But at this point, I can reliably turn the problem on/off, so I should be able to create a minimal example.  I'll update....

Waiting for your update. :)

@JessieZhang-MSFT: see this post https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/24545

@JessieZhang-MSFT and see this minimal code sample to reproduce  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mCSkiVGwSh3aHpwCZXhUb-AvEo4QNttv/view?usp=sharing

PS: To be clear This was not a random page navigation but a crash that revealed the last page on the stack which happened to be the Azure login.

Full related Stack Overflow issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78916555/net-maui-exceptions-not-caught-in-release-build-android/78927200?noredirect=1#comment139165980_78927200

Since you have posted an issue, then be patient and wait for the update from the Microsoft development team. Thank you very much for your support and feedback. :)
