.NET MAUI Exceptions Not Caught in RELEASE build (Android)
It looks like exceptions thrown under a release build are not caught in exception handling:
Here is code and logs generated when running under a DEBUG build and a RELEASE build:
   try
   {
      Flog.Info("Force exception. Should be caught and logged next...");
      object someObj = null; 
      someObj.GetType();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Flog.Error(e); // Log error
   }

Here is the log under RELEASE BUILD:
    [2024-08-26][18:50:01.0863]:INFO:Force an exception. Should be caught and logged next...
    // (and nothing else logged - app crashes)

Under DEBUG...
    [2024-08-26][18:56:07.0897]:INFO:Force exception.  Should be caught and logged next...
    [2024-08-26] 
    [18:56:11.0326]:ERROR:DescriptionModels.DescriptiveText:Object reference not set to an instance of an object....

SO... it is clear that under a RELEASE build exceptions are not caught.
WHY IS THIS?  Is there a compiler switch of some sort?

MORE INFORMATION AND MINIMAL EXAMPLE:
The link below has a ZIP file with a solution and project that demonstrates this problem.

Run a release build of the project "TestException".  You will see two buttons: One that will force a null reference exception and another that starts a background thread that sends a ping request once a second, using thje NetworkInformation.Ping class.

Click on the button to force an exception a few times.  You'll see a popup alert reporting the null reference when the exception is caught.

Then click on the button to start the background Ping thread.

Once that thread is started, click on the button to force an exception again.  This time, you'll see that the app just abends and quits.  The exception handler is never called.

NOTE: The background thread does not have to be running for this problem to occur: It only needs to run once.  If it is run once, then stopped, the problem will still occur if you force the exception again.


Minimal code project to demonstrate the issue
Note that this problem ONLY occurs in RELEASE builds.  Debug builds do NOT have this issue.
SO:  What is in the Ping class that causes this issue? OR... what is wrong with the code that causes the issue only in release builds?
GitHub Issue Logged Here

ANOTHER UPDATE:
It is not necessary to even run the background thread.  Simply calling "Ping" will trigger the issue.


Why not use official method to log error? And please provide a Minimal, Reproducible sample.

@Jianwei : The error logging is not the problem, the problem is that exception handling is different in release builds (absent) vs debug builds.   The code sequence above is all that is needed to illustrate the error.  (Substitute Debug.Writeline for our Flog wrapper)

@Jianwei:  I just created a new project to reproduce this.  Interesting that the new project does NOT show the same problem, although the code example is the same.  So the question is:  What might be different in the actual project that is causing exceptions to be ignored in release build?   Any idea what could cause this?  I've examined the project settings and can find no real differences. What should I look for?

Delete bin and obj file of your previous project and then run to see if it catch exception in release build.

Hi, @JianweiSun-MSFT : I tried this, but it did not make a difference.  What I did do was to create a brand new empty project, verify that exceptions are caught [ ((object)null).GetType() to throw ] then copied ALL the code from the original project into the new one.   In the new project, there is no problem catching exceptions.  I also noticed that I am getting different compiler warnings in the new project.  This is odd.  Seems like a different version of the compiler?  Or.. different settings.  Very very strange.

I also noticed that I am getting different compiler warnings in the new project. This is odd. Seems like a different version of the compiler? Or.. different settings. Yes, about VS,  I have also encountered some strange problems before. You can report it on Developer Community/Visual Studio.

MORE ON THIS:  App has a startup sequence in MainActivity before displaying main page.   This consists of 1. getting permissions, 2. performing database & config tests and 3. starting a network monitor to check server connectivity.   I methodically removed each sequence and found the problem with "no catch" went away if I removed the network monitor!   In the network monitor, I also removed code to narrow down.  It appears that removing small amount of code to "Ping" an internet endpoint remedied the problem.  Do NOT understand how a ping could affect exception handling.  Any explanations?

Does this exist in the new project or in the old project?

@JianweiSun-MSFT : In the new project.  I haven't had time to reproduce in the old project yet.   But instead of doing that, I'm going to try isolating the behavior in a minimal "hello world" type app, now that I know the "trigger".   I'll update....

@JianweiSun-MSFT : I have edited the original post to include a link to ZIP file with a project that demonstrates the problem with a minimal amount of code.  This reliably reproduces the problem when run on my system.  Please try it on yours, and let me know if you also see the same issue.  Thanks.

This is not a "solution" but it is indeed an answer.
The issue here was related to use of the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class. Calling the Ping() method on this class somehow "steals" the exception handling such that subsequent exceptions are not caught - and ONLY in RELEASE builds.
See this GitHub explanation
Removing the use of this class solved the problem.
The underlying issue should be the topic of a different thread.

Well, as an answer:

it is clear that under a RELEASE build exceptions are not caught...

Creating a brand new empty project and moving the code from the original project into the new one can catch exceptions on release and debug mode normally.

At first, this seemed to work.  Now, after making some changes to options such as size optimization, etc. (turning it off), the problem has reoccurred in the new project.  I've had a LOT of software development experience, but this is problem is very very bizarre and difficult to diagnose.  I'm going to take the opposite approach, which is to take a brand new "hello world" type project and see what I have to do to make the problem appear.  This is most definitely some sort of Maui bug, however....

About this, you can report it on MAUI issue GitHub.
